# Directing cmp output to a file using python

Tags: python, linux

I am trying something like this, but I am not sure why its not working.

```
 for files in os.listdir("."):
    if files.endswith(".o"):
       str = "cmp "+ str1+"  "+str2 +" > s.txt "
       subprocess.Popen(str, shell=True)
```

If I dont have `te.txt`, I get output, but when I try to direct the output to a file, the file is not created. Can someone tell me what's wrong here?

Comment: `cmp` takes two parameters & compares them. Usually, if only one input is specific as command line arguments, then it reads from stdin instead of the second file. You are specifying only one file, and not writing to child's stdin.

Comment: sorry my bad..mistake while copying.. corrected it

Comment: Please edit your question. As it stands, we can hardly make **any** sense. Whats `te.txt`? Whats `str1`? Whats `str2`? What is the output you're expecting? What happens when you execute? What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
import os

for files in os.listdir("."):
    if files.endswith(".o"):
       str = "cmp "+ str1+"  "+str2 +" > s.txt "
       os.system(str)
```

And if you use `subprocess` you need put all arguments as list of words
for example:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(["ls", "-la"])
```

And the last remark, you don't need put output from `... > file.txt`, you can make it using `subprocess`. For example

```
subprocess.Popen(["ls", "-la"], stdout=anyfile)
```